# 100vh, 50% and responsiveness

Tags: html, css

I have these stacked div's that are `height: 100vh;` (polyfills are present). Then inside of that div, I have 8 div's that are are suppose to be a perfect square, i use the `width: 0;` and `padding-left: 25%;` trick for that. but I would like to know how can I get the 2 rows to always fit inside the `height: 100vh;` div and scale down maintaining that `1:1` ratio.

I have supplied a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhaef0wd/) to get started.

Comment: JSFiddle is nice, but please put the relevant parts in your question too. Also note that SO has a JSFiddle-like feature built in.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks. `.entropy` needs to be a perfect square regardless of the viewports height, and still fit 2 rows of 4 perfectly. Whether white space top and bottom or left and right gets created that's fine too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could set both height and width of `.entropy` to 25% of viewport height. That way they will always be squared.

You then might want to clear floats every 5th square.

```css
.wrap {
    height: 100vh;
    zoom: 1;
}

.wrap:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.entropy {
    float: left;
    width: 25vh;
    height: 25vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.entropy:nth-of-type(5n) {
    clear: left;
}

.entropy:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: '';
    height: 100%; 
}

.entropy p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="entropy">
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:** An alternative is to do something like this:

```
.entropy {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.entropy:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 25vw;
}
```

This way centering everything is easier, but you may have to change your HTML a little.

Here an example based on viewport width: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky0keknL/)**.

And here an example based on viewport height: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky0keknL/1/)**.

Comment: With this, how would you then center those floated items?